# PHP session variable security

Tags: php, security, session-variables

Is it a bad idea to store a raw sql query in a php session variable for later use? Does this present any security issues?

Comment: I can't fathom such a need ever arising? Can you please elaborate? There might be a better way...

Comment: I can't see why you would do this, either... but it's pretty safe unless you have shared hosting.

Comment: The query is being created by data the user posts to the site, however when the query generates 100s of results we want to paginate without resubmitting the post; So I'm storing the query as a variable and offsetting it depending on if there is a url segment for pagination.

Comment: because it is based off of user inputted data I wouldn't. It opens a possibility for them to inject code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the session data is stored in a file in the server’s file system (see [*session.save_handler*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) and [*session.save_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)). If you protect that session data (e.g. by protecting the directory to be accessible only by PHP or your web server), you can put sensible data into your session.

Note that if you’re on a shared host, it’s very probably that all users on that shared host have access to that session data directory. In that case you should either change that directory to one that only you have access to or change the session save handler to store the session data in your personal database or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

It is theoretically a 'safe' practice, but not generally advisable.  It is safe if you protect your session data correctly, however as a rule of thumb, I would say you shouldn't really do it in most cases.

Is there a reason you cannot re-generate this SQL when it is later needed?  Perhaps your methodology is wrong, or you are not re-using your application code enough.

More specific details and perhaps example code for your distinct circumstance will yield a better response.

Answer (score 1):

PHP session variables are stored on the *server*; The browser is only given a *key* for that data. The server generates this key randomly and associates the session data with that key. When the client requests for a page, the session mechanism matches the key to the data and thus knows who the client is. The data itself is never exposed to the client, only the key is, so you're safe.